# GUI Builder for Titanium Developer

Tags: user-interface, titanium, gui-designer

Is there any gui builder available for titanium desktop/mobile applications?

I have been using javascript to write that buttons/labels code.

Is there any drag and drop facility available in titanium?

Answer (score 5):

Checkout ForgedUI http://www.forgedui.com/  ForgedUI is a Drag and Drop UI builder for Titanium.

It costs $99, but you can test it out for free (you only can save 10 times). Here is the link [in the Titanium Marketplace.](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1237?1657293241)

Comment: ForgedUI is officially closed

Answer (score 0):

I use [codiqa.com](http://codiqa.com) and its awesome.. Probably the best till date. I am looking for something better than this... and good if that's free ! :-)

Comment: I don't see any titanium related info on their website. They export to PhoneGap, but that's about it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yep. Its a Jquery Mobile Tool with PhoneGap export.. But, I found some tool on youtube, and I have no idea about what tool it is. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wgjLfAZCD0

Comment: It is mentioned in an answer here. It seems as a beta, I also couldn't find info on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I found a tool called **Visual UI**:
http://visual-ui.com/

It is a **paid** eclipse plugin, but it has a **free trial** unlike ForgeUI. It works only with **Alloy** AFAIK. Alloy is the xml gui creation api in Titanium 3.0.

I haven't investigated thoroughly, so if someone has used this, please comment.

From what I see there is no syncing between xml and the gui perspective, but again don't take my word for it - my experience is far too limited.

It costs [$20/yr](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/2590?1657813202) which is less than ForgeUI.

Comment: I would avoid visual-ui at all costs. Although the youtube video shows it working, I've had no end of problems with it causing my TS to stop responding. Their tech support has not been forthcoming For me its a matter for PayPal, since they choose to take money for a product which has severe reliability issues and they won't respond to them.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through with many Ui thing i found this interesting  http://visual-ui.com/

VisualUI for Titanium Studio is a plugin that allows WYSIWYG creation of user interfaces for the Titanium Appcelerator platform using drag and drop with an internal editor and external designers using the target device simulators.
Works as a pluging on all platforms supported by Titanium Studio. Native Alloy development or standard Appcelerator SDK supported.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is one drag and drop tool... TUB Titanium UI Builder http://titaniumui.com
 its cool.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TiSmithy](http://www.tismithy.com), it is easy to use and in the Mac App Store.

The way it works is very simple. You add the elements you would like into your layout, then edit the attributes and finally hit "generate code". It will output both alloy and classic code that's ready to use.

The only thing you'll need to change is the image paths to reference the folder locations within your project itself.

In the latest version Fluid elements were added. These appear on all screens, while the fixed elements appear only on the screen you add them. There's a trial on the site if you want to see how it works.